# Error in env_bind_lazy(private$bindings, !!!set_names(promises, names_bindings)) : attempt to use zero-length variable name

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to filter every column of my dataframe with a certain threshold (in this case >= 1.2) with dplyrs filter function. It worked nicely so far, but suddenly I get this error message, when I try to run the code:

> Error in env_bind_lazy(private$bindings, !!!set_names(promises, names_bindings)) :
> attempt to use zero-length variable name

This is part of my dataframe (it has 108 columns, some rows contain NA):

| Mean 1 | Mean 2 | Mean 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1874 | 1.0944 | 1.2376 |
| 1.2258 | 1.0665 | 1.2365 |
| 1.0953 | 1.1420 | 1.2479 |
| 1.2234 | 1.0949 | 1.0608 |
| NA | NA | 1.146 |

This is my code:

```
Heights_filtered = list()
for (i in 1:length(allHeights)){
  filtered = filter(allHeights, allHeights[,i] >=1.2, .preserve = TRUE)
  filterlist = cbind.data.frame(filtered[,i])
  colnames(filterlist) = colnames(allHeights[i])
  Heights_filtered[[i]] = cbind.data.frame(filterlist)
  names(Heights_filtered) = colnames(allHeights[i])}
```

Do you have an idea why this happens now?
Thanks for your help!

These are the first rows of my dataframe

```
> dput(head(allHeights[1:10], 10))
structure(list(Mean1 = c(1.18743006611931, 1.22582285838843, 
1.09595291724188, 1.22341059362058, 1.32431882583739, 1.31219937513623, 
1.28004068880331, 1.29884472862021, 1.36733270362566, 1.38170457022452
), Mean2 = c(1.09447069039104, 1.09233667417252, 1.08767127319823, 
1.06656658866469, 1.14203717603426, 1.09491221098798, 1.03171589621323, 
1.15308990831089, 1.17585765375955, 1.11962264706315), Mean3 = c(1.23761700966768, 
1.07486913672867, 1.2605330014152, 1.21512728264762, 1.23659397432181, 
1.17488789237668, 1.28191444014391, 1.23137649405787, 1.22165765827209, 
1.17481969002029), Mean4 = c(1.0608309164187, 1.06201740178538, 
1.07512524012204, 1.07230027496328, 1.07823270179668, 1.08137782967343, 
1.08704659309202, 1.09783795999849, 1.05538815021281, 1.04118799201477
), Mean5 = c(1.3872325431161, 1.34236438736957, 1.11657498580741, 
1.19758040835503, 1.19718888867138, 1.12759626490222, 1.13074799835562, 
1.19262768435683, 1.16498639469099, 1.2131433157802), Mean6 = c(1.18440664423239, 
1.20342967777624, 1.21238802071329, 1.12420289186988, 1.22123880207133, 
1.19712964243458, 1.20605725349191, 1.23989305305859, 1.21075923108837, 
1.24834431998033), Mean7 = c(1.13543425248546, 1.12286625398612, 
1.09469483808257, 1.10461963472656, 1.11445916679456, 1.08465067103221, 
1.12117801538173, 1.08284306202145, 1.11304377483331, 1.13541719957027
), Mean8 = c(1.24793883159642, 1.19395390601616, 1.18592691355337, 
1.19717830807325, 1.191232891622, 1.19336888792142, 1.17576392479116, 
1.13564256754918, 1.11424178933907, 1.18585888819352), Mean9 = c(1.20505670697375, 
1.18604713515832, 1.19024318309784, 1.21607636002896, 1.30812129661903, 
1.24325012735609, 1.19658417567097, 1.27798482451672, 1.04137061962088, 
1.30975681690216), Mean10 = c(1.06327665140615, 1.13939757285081, 
1.12462757067074, 1.06967153549887, 1.08647627352663, 1.16336022091418, 
1.15385873119686, 1.1672116851973, 1.22303975001817, 1.13392922026016
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here the last part of the dataframe which gives me the error:

```
dput(head(allHeights[100:108], 10))
structure(list(c(1.3975238170743, 1.42479618398277, 1.36302374440084, 
1.33075672890157, 1.30214981303101, 1.29526565452359, 1.31860044132609, 
1.23876534400972, 1.15907559361002, 1.26664552529697), c(2.22279564798051, 
2.15443577725511, 2.36887256975583, 2.04737812822552, 2.21183099544832, 
2.08881706966277, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(1.03731717809005, 1.07517206767995, 
1.10263120160597, 1.17071264697448, 1.12660596501291, 1.07340120447376, 
1.05339833667909, 1.02742328649269, 1.04743332377402, 1.09359764840837
), c(1.75325898322414, 1.80777043843246, 1.26273660420002, 1.59312822030592, 
1.11652967053664, 1.62459472912435, 1.28563356786353, 1.95060067533935, 
NA, NA), c(1.34261413268355, 1.30548480529631, 1.32490460208726, 
1.05392855500896, 1.36887499425314, 1.12776424072456, 1.24322559882304, 
1.24394280722725, 1.51098340306193, 1.35122063353409), c(1.30861179458687, 
1.30802444638463, 1.32818477656957, 1.2115882212874, 1.27803793951901, 
1.34488451464402, 1.2494642431939, 1.14564647987936, 1.13223271688229, 
1.21111199301532), c(1.19828142850047, 1.2299458600308, 1.18492028013709, 
1.24207768340535, 1.14210500173844, 1.14374410172354, 1.17129836586698, 
1.20543386479909, 1.17938210897531, 1.1315377738042), c(1.06870742201506, 
1.19744233297478, 1.14709573323772, 1.21291980399187, 1.19923509023545, 
1.1095972272021, 1.1777817616828, 1.13757918011235, 1.18910601171268, 
1.18139715549181), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Mean100", 
"Mean101", "Mean102", "Mean103", "Mean104", "Mean105", "Mean106", 
"Mean107", NA), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution might work and be more inline with a `dplyr` approach. The code below uses mtcars as an example. It will keep rows where all values are greater than or equal to one.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
    filter(
        across(
            .cols = everything(),
            .fns = ~ .x >= 1
        )
    
    )
```

Edit: Depending if you want to handle missing data this should help. You can specify your function you want to use to filter and then apply in in the where statement. Here is another example with mtcars.

```
myrowfun <- function(x){is.na(x)| x >=2}
mtcars <- mutate(mtcars, mpg = NA)
mtcars$mpg[1:7] <- rep(1,7)

mtcars %>% 
  filter(myrowfun(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns = ~.x
    )
  )
  )
```

edit: adding an example of how to remove all missing columns

```
mtcars <- mutate(mtcars, newcol = NA)
#shows which columns are not all missing
sapply(mtcars, function(x)all(!is.na(x)))

#subset on that 
mtcars2 <- mtcars[, sapply(mtcars, function(x)all(!is.na(x)))]
```

Comment: can you try to restart your R session and try again? what version of dplyr/tidyverse are you using.

Comment: Restarting my session did also not help. I use dplyr version 1.0.2
Interestingly, subsetting my df and then filter this subset with my code does work...

Comment: very interesting, I think I would need to see your data to help with the issue. If you can share it you can use `dput(yourdf)` and copy that into your question. If you are happy with your solution then disregard this

Comment: I posted the first 10 rows and columns of my df, since it is a quite big df with 20 rows and over 100 columns. Please tell me, if you need more info.

Comment: thank you for that. When I run on that subset I do not get an error. can you create a subset that gives you that error and then post that?

Comment: So I also added the last columns of my df. I think its the last column, which only contains NA, that causes my problem... Since in that case I can just use a subset without these last column the code works for me now. However I am still not sure, why it causes these problems... Since I have a lot of dfs that are similar to the one I posted,  I don't want to check all of them for empty columns beforehand...

Comment: I added another example to show how to remove all missing cols with mtcars, I am not sure of a solution where you wouldn't have to do this if it is throwing the error

Comment: Thank you! Managed to fix it by removing all NA columns.

Comment: ok great! if this answer was helpful please hit the up arrow and accept as the correct solution